# C code to swap two integers by passing pointers to a swap function

Tags: c, pointers

I encountered this problem while solving a practice test

Consider this C code to swap two integers and these five statements:

```
void swap (int *px, int *py) {

*px = *px – *py;

*py = *px + *py;

*px = *py – *px;

}
```

S1: will generate a compilation error

S2: may generate a segmentation fault at runtime depending on the arguments  passed

S3: correctly implements the swap procedure for all input pointers referring to  integers stored in memory locations accessible to the process

S4: implements the swap procedure correctly for some but not all valid input  pointers

S5: may add or subtract integers and pointers.

Which of the above statement(s) is/are correct?

I think S2 and S3. Could anyone please confirm

Comment: *Why* do you think S2 and S3 are correct?  I'm not going to do your homework (and I hope no one else will either), but we might be willing to point out any flaws in your reasoning.

Comment: It's not homework; anyway my reasoning was S2 is correct as any of the two pointers might be pointing to a segment not accessible to this program and I thought S3 was correct considering few sample values but as someone pointed out it won't work in case px == py

Comment: In C99 you could try the `restrict` keyword `void swap(int *restrict px, int *restrict py);`. Of course, enforcing the "restrictness" of the pointers is a job for the calling code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe S3 holds, since if you call it with `px == py`, it will just set the integer to 0 in the first line (`*px = *px - *py` is then equivalent to `*px = *px - *px` which obviously stores a 0 in `*px`). With all input data set to 0, it's unable to recover and re-generate the value.

Comment: +1: just to make it clearer ... if you call your function with `swap(&var, &var)` no matter what `var` started with (and barring undefined overflow issues) it will end up with `0`.

Comment: Are you sure? *px may be 0 but *py still has the original value. Subsequent statements just adds and substracts from *py which just gives back whatever *py is.

Comment: ok I see what you mean, pmg's comment made it clear it's an aliasing problem. I was thinking `*px == *py`.

Comment: I'd say it depends on the wording of the problem or its interpretation. If we take it as "swap 2 integers" = "swap values of 2 distinct integer variables", no problem.

Comment: @Alex: There's still a problem even if the integers are distinct, because the first subtraction can overflow.

Comment: @caf: That I've already mentioned in my comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994714/c-code-to-swap-two-integers-by-passing-pointers-to-a-swap-function/7994839#7994839).

Answer (score 2):

```
S1: False, the code will compile
S2: True, never checks for NULL
S3: False, as unwind pointed out, if px == py it would fail
S4: True for the case cited above
S5: False, never subtracts any pointers
```

edit: i was wrong saying the code doesnt swap :)

Comment: Do the math, it really swaps things... (kinda like the xor trick)

Comment: Doesn't have to be NULL, a pointer to a read-only location or to a location where some object used to be but no longer is (free()'d) and there's no accessible memory would suffice. And you answered the opposite of S3.

Comment: really? I will have to take a look then :)

Comment: @Alex the funcition clearly states that it doesn't accept const pointers so that is implicity and the compiler would bark at you if you try to pass a const pointer. As for a dangling pointer, well, you can't ever prevent that in C.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, but know that (signed) integer overflow yields undefined behaviour. That may slightly alter your answers.

Comment: Signed integer overflow, that is. Unsigned is OK.

Answer (score 0):

- S2 is true.
- S4 is true, because S3 is false due to aliasing problem.
- rest is false

Without aliasing problem it really would swap values:

px                                              | py
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
px := px-py                                 |
                                                  | py := px+py => px-py+py = px
px := py-px => px-(px-py) = py   |

Comment: Speaking of S4, for what kind of valid pointers will the swap not work? What is your interpretation of the word 'valid'?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Right. I think the problem wording is important here. And either it has to be clarified or the answer has to be made conditional on the interpretation of the problem.